# Sorting By:Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I am little bit confused regarding worst Case time and Avg case Time complexity. My source of confusion is  [Here](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/cs14/cs14_06win/slides/BinarySearchTrees.pdf)

My aim is to short data in increasing Order: I choose BST to acomplish my task of sorting.Here I am putting what I am doing for printing data in Increasing order.

```
 1) Construct a binary search tree for given input.
        Time complexity: Avg Case O(log n)
                         Worst Case O(H) {H is height of tree, here we can Assume Height is equal to number of node H = n}

 2)After Finishing first work I am traversing BST in Inorder to print data in Increasing order. 
        Time complexity: O(n) {n is the number of nodes in tree}

Now  I analyzed total complexity for get my desire result (data in increasing order) is for Avg Case: T(n) = O(log n) +O(n) = max(log n, n) = O(n)
      For Worst Case : T(n) = O(n) +O(n) = max(n, n) = O(n)
```

Above point was my understanding which is Differ from Above Link concept. I know I am doing some wrong interpratation Please correct me. I would appreciate your suggestion and thought.

Please Refer this title Under Slide which I have mentined:
    [image]

Comment: Can you point out something specific in the slides that is confusing. I am not quite sure.

Comment: @Justin: Sure I just take screenshot and Post it.

Comment: Even after reviewing the linked information, I'm not real sure what your actual question is. However, it should be fairly evident that, no matter what your data structure is, there is no way to visit every node in anything less than O(n). Inserting (or deleting or searching) a single node may be O(log n), but building the entire tree obviously inserts every node, so it would take n * O(log n) == O(n log n) - maybe that's what you're missing. Your item (1) quotes the average/worst time for a single insertion, not building the entire tree.

Comment: @Thanks Twalberg Now I got your point...Once again thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (1) you provide the time per element, you need to multiply with the # of elements.

Comment: You mean n Time in each Insertion of element, I mean If we have four elment {1,2,3,4}  and each have cost 5 then Total Cost  = 5*1 +5*1 +5*1 +5*1, By this way In BST n element will take n^2 Time. Am I correct Stefan

Comment: Yes. The cost for one insertion in the worst case is O(H). So the cost for n insertions is O(n * n).

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity needed to construct the binary tree is n times the complexity you suggest as you need to insert each node.